# What forces a C++ compiler to actually perform thread synchronization operations?

Tags: c++, multithreading, language-lawyer

Here's a classic kind of multithreaded algorithm - don't mind the lack of practical utility:

```
std::atomic<bool> turn;
std::atomic<int> counter;
void thread(bool thread_id) {
    for(;;) {
        if(turn.load(std::memory_order::acquire) == thread_id) {
            counter += 1;
            turn.store(!thread_id, std::memory_order::release);
        } else {
            printf("spinning");
        }
    }
}
// run thread(true) and thread(false) concurrently
```

Compilers can optimize atomic variables, such as merging consecutive loads and stores, and it can move other operations after a load-acquire or before a store-release. **So** what prevents the compiler from transforming the code into something like this?

```
void thread(bool thread_id) {
    bool turn_ = turn.load(std::memory_order::acquire);
    for(;;) {
        if(turn_ == thread_id) {
            counter += 1;
            turn_ = !thread_id;
        } else {
            printf("spinning");
        }
    }
    turn.store(turn_, std::memory_order::release);
}
```

or even this?

```
void thread(bool thread_id) {
    if(turn.load(std::memory_order::acquire) == thread_id) {
        counter += 1;
    }
    for(;;) {
        printf("spinning");
    }
}
```

Comment: Compilers can optimize *provided* they don't break any guarantees the language (or that particular compiler) makes. Code is correct if it doesn't rely on any guarantees not proided by the language or, if that code is compiler-specific, the compiler. If your mutex code is correct, it does what it's supposed to do because it doesn't rely on guarantees it doesn't have.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz No shit. What guarantee is broken by the compiler doing this?

Comment: In the case of your last paragraph, you can't say without seeing the code for the mutex. But if the mutex code allows the compiler to break it without the compiler having to break any guarantees, then the mutex code is broken.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz and what guarantee is broken by the compiler moving unsynchronized code inside the scope of a mutex being locked?

Comment: If no guaratnee was broken by that happening, then code that assumed that wouldn't happen in order to operate reliably would itself be broken. Mutexes are defined to include barriers in their lock and unlock operations and provide specific guarantees about their behavior. Correct code relies only on guarantees it actually has. (That's why I think the code in  the beginning of your question is just broken. It relies on guarantees it does not have, so it *might* work.)

Answer (score 1):

> it can move other operations after a load-acquire or before a store-release.

This is not accurate phrasing.  `printf()` is an I/O operation, and those can't be moved across.

Your second snippet of code is an invalid as-if transformation, because in the original code, there's a `turn.load()` call between consecutive `printf()` calls, and the proposed optimization breaks that.

> Reading an object designated by a volatile glvalue ([basic.lval]), modifying an object, **calling a library I/O function**, or calling a function that does any of those operations are all side effects, which are changes in the state of the execution environment.

- https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.exec#intro.execution-7

> Every value computation and side effect associated with a full-expression is sequenced before every value computation and side effect associated with the next full-expression to be evaluated.

- https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.exec#intro.execution-9

Comment: Which rule says that `printf` and `turn.load` can't be interchanged?

Comment: @user253751 https://eel.is/c++draft/intro.progress#3.3

Comment: Which rule says that execution steps can't be interchanged?

Comment: @user253751: https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.exec#intro.execution-7 and https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.exec#intro.execution-9 (They don't use the terminology of "execution step" but they provide for guaranteed ordering of the same list of side effects)

Comment: intro.execution-7 does not guarantee this because it does not say anything about atomic operations. Sequenced-before is only a single-threaded guarantee AFAIK (although it can be used with synchronization operations to create sequencing across threads)

Comment: @user253751: Yes, the sequenced-before relationship interacts with the synchronization action of the atomic.  https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.exec#intro.races-9.3  The Standard only talks in terms of the resulting behavior, but it's equivalent to forbidding moving cross-thread observable side effects such as I/O across other cross-thread observable operations such as atomic or volatile memory access.

Comment: The fact that "library I/O functions" are included in all the lists of operations with threading implications should clue you in without having to follow the chain of two dozen rules.  @user253751 asked me for a single rule, but nothing in this area of the Standard is described in a single specific rule, even something as plain as the fact that atomic writes are in fact atomic (observers cannot read a torn value) involves numerous rules working together.

Comment: The atomic operation only provides an inter-thread-happens-before relation when another thread reads the value written in this thread, which does not happen if the compiler does this reordering, so the rule is not broken.

Comment: @user253751: Incorrect.  Atomic operations within a single thread also satisfy inter-thread-happens-before conditions.  Also, the test is done on the code as-written, not after your proposed optimization has broken its behavior.  Otherwise I could optimize everything to `(void)0;` and look, no need to synchronize.

Comment: that provides an inter-thread-happens-before between two operations on the same thread which is not very helpful because they are already sequenced-before

Answer (score 1):

The transformations you describe are possible. A compiler can transform a piece of code using atomic operations or mutexes into one in which an atomic store operation or mutex unlock operation takes forever to become visible to every other thread.

With your first example, it is, in fact, possible that one thread sees a value of `turn` that matches its `thread_id`, flips the value of `turn`, increments `counter`, and then will never see `turn` flipped back, because the other thread loops forever while still seeing the initial value of `turn`. The compiler can use the fact that this is possible to elide any further reads from `turn` by the first thread; it is already known that such reads will take their value from the store that the same thread already performed. In the case of mutexes, it is indeed possible that one thread locks the mutex, does some operations, and then unlocks the mutex and goes on doing other operations, while other threads waiting to lock the mutex never wake up.

Now, the standard does have this to say ([[intro.progress]/18](http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.progress#18)):

> An implementation should ensure that the last value (in modification order) assigned by an atomic or synchronization operation will become visible to all other threads in a finite period of time.

This is basically saying that an implementation in which it takes forever for a thread to see the value stored by a different thread to an atomic variable is very naughty, but not technically breaking the law (since this sentence uses the word "should" instead of "shall"). In practice, compilers will try to ensure that a value written to an atomic variable (or a later value in the variable's modification order) becomes visible to other threads as soon as the hardware allows. Any other behaviour would not be useful for their customers.

Comment: so it is not guaranteed by the standard at all, but we get to yell at the compiler writers if they don't guarantee it anyway?

Comment: @user253751 Of course you can. No one wants to use a compiler that takes deliberately hostile interpretations of the standard that make atomic variables nearly useless.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler cannot adapt the code like in your two examples for a very simple reason. `turn` is not a variable, it is an atomic variable. There are strict rules for atomic variables : apply exactly what is written, all access is insecable, including actions on the cache (the std::memory_order flags).

mutex need use atomic variables, but it's not sufficient, it also need some process synchronisation mechanism.

You're right, implementation of atomic can be done by:

- take a mutex
- do access on the atomic variable
- release the mutex

So the equivalent in that case is:

```
void thread(bool thread_id) {
    for(;;) {
        take mutex
        if ( turn == thread_id ) {
            release mutex
            counter += 1;
            take mutex
            turn = !thread_id
            release mutex
        } else {
            release mutex
            printf("spinning");
        }
    }
}
```

So the mutex is taken **only when needed**.

Comment: what doess unsecable mean?

Comment: @user253751 it's a  typo. insecable.. kind of continous, uninterrupted https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/insecable

Comment: atomic access more complex in structure than locking access if different memory ordering is used.

Comment: Compilers are allowed to combine multiple loads or stores to the same atomic variable.